# Why is selector.text getting an internal function value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In a `$.ajax success` function I am trying to run a delay before making another call.  My document has a `<DIV ID="status"></DIV>` element, so the first step here works fine:

```
$("#status").text = "Refreshing";
```

But when I try to add ellipses to that text via a `setInterval` function like this:

```
var count = 0;
var waitingID = setInterval(waiting, 1000);
function waiting() {
    if(count == 5) {
        clearInterval(waitingID);
        CallUpdate();
    }
    else {
        count++;
        var notice = $("#status");
        notice.text(notice.text + ".");
    }
}
```

the text in that `DIV` becomes

> function ( value ) {      return access( this, function( value ) {
>             return value === undefined ?
>                 jQuery.text( this ) :
>                 this.empty().each(function() {
>                     if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
>                         this.textContent = value;
>                     }
>                 });         }, null, value, arguments.length );     }.

What is going on?  Why isn't the `notice.text(notice.text + ".");` simply appending a `.` to the text in the `DIV`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your function. You are just using jQuery's [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text) function incorrectly.

```js
$('#status').text('Refreshing');
var count = 0;
var waitingID = setInterval(waiting, 1000);
function waiting() {
    if(count == 5) {
        clearInterval(waitingID);
        console.log('CallUpdate()');
    }
    else {
        count++;
        var notice = $("#status");
        notice.text(notice.text() + ".");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="status"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `text()` is a function, not a property, to be used as `$("#status").text("Refreshing");`

It does however accept a callback you can use for concatenating text, like this

```
var notice = $("#status");
notice.text(function(_,txt) {
    return txt + "."
});
```

---

When you do `notice.text(notice.text + ".");` you're trying to add a period to a function reference

Comment: I believe it takes a regular string as well, so could just as well be `notice.text(txt + ".")`

Comment: Yes, it would take any regular string, but `notice.text` is not a string, it's an object, or more specifically a function, that the OP is trying to concatenate to a string

Comment: Oh, shoot, that's right.  The shorthand I must have been thinking of is `notice.text(notice.text() + ".");`.  << that works nicely

Comment: @feetwet - yes, that would work, calling the function to return the text